# displying large dataframe by dataTables using Server-side processing

Tags: flask, datatables

I'm trying to convert very large dataframe (pandas) to dataTables using Server-side processing without success so far.  I'm attaching dataframe for example with 2 rows only but my original dataframe is around 20K rows with 14 columns..

Flask

```
 @app.route(rule='/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def index():
   df_to_table = pd.DataFrame({'First name':['Airi', 'Angelica'], 'Last name': ['Satou', 'Ramos'], 'Position': ['Accountant', 'Chief Executive Officer (CEO)'], 'Office': ['Tokyo', 'London'], 'Start date': ['28th Nov 08', '9th Oct 09'], 'Salary': ['$162,700', '$1,200,000']})

   ''' print of df_to_table:
        First name  Last name   Position                       Office   Start date   Salary
    0   Airi        Satou       Accountant                     Tokyo    28th Nov 08  $162,700
    1   Angelica    Ramos       Chief Executive Officer (CEO)  London   9th Oct 09   $1,200,000
   '''
   df_to_table = df_to_table.to_json(orient='split')
   return render_template('table.html', df_to_table=df_to_table)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
   ...
  </head>

  <body>
     <table id="sortTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>First name</th>
           <th>Last name</th>
           <th>Position</th>
           <th>Office</th>
           <th>Start date</th>
           <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>

   <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dataTables.js')}}"></script>
   <script>$(document).ready(start({{ df_to_table | safe }}));</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function start(df_to_table) {
  return function() {
    $('#sortTable').DataTable ({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": df_to_table,
    });
  };
};
```

Error On Screen
[image]

Network
[image]

Log

```
Object { columns: (6) […], index: (2) […], data: (2) […] }
​
columns: Array(6) [ "First name", "Last name", "Position", … ]
  0: "First name"
  1: "Last name"
  2: "Position"
  3: "Office"
  4: "Start date"
  5: "Salary"
  length: 6​​
  <prototype>: Array []
​
data: Array [ (6) […], (6) […] ]
  0: Array(6) [ "Airi", "Satou", "Accountant", … ]
  1: Array(6) [ "Angelica", "Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", … ]​​
length: 2
<prototype>: Array []
​
index: Array [ 0, 1 ]
  0: 0
  1: 1
  length: 2
  <prototype>: Array []
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

JSON output as text:

> {"columns":["First name","Last name","Position","Office","Start
> date","Salary"],"index":[0,1],"data":[["Airi","Satou","Accountant","Tokyo","28th
> Nov 08","$162,700"],["Angelica","Ramos","Chief Executive Officer
> (CEO)","London","9th Oct 09","$1,200,000"]]}

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show what the raw JSON (as text) looks like?

Comment: Side note: Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) when asking a question.

Comment: @andrewjames I attached the raw JSON and how it looks when I console log it. and thank you for your comment and clarification for why should I not upload images.

Comment: OK - the JSON is valid and should be displayed (but extra data will be need to be added to fully support server-side processing). First of all, however, I would simplify your JS down to one script as follows: `$(document).ready(function() { $('#sortTable').DataTable( { "ajax": "your URL goes here" } ); } );`. Get that working first - then you may be able to see how to alter your Flask template accordingly, to avoid hard-coding the URL. Sorry, my Flask skills are very poor.